# IIS7 & ASP: Dll Access denied

Tags: python, windows, dll, iis-7, asp-classic

I have a ASP Classic script which is served via IIS7. I am using it in conjunction with Python Script, which in turn uses ctypes to access a C DLL. However, python is throwing an exception when I try accessing the DLL via IIS7. How do I setup the permissions for the DLL? Do I do something in IIS7's configuration or do I add specific user privileges to the file itself via Windows explorer?

Answer (score 0):

Did you regester your dll ?

At the command prompt, type:

```
regsvr32 dllpath
```